# Checking whether socket port is available

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

**Situation:**

I have an application, which has a TCP server as its part (based on `socketserver`), and I wanna test it functionally.

I've created myself a testing mixin, which I use in every test case:

```
class AppProcessManagingMixin:
    _used_tcp_ports = set()

    def start_my_app(self):
        port = self._take_tcp_port()
        prepare_config_with_given_tcp_port(port)
        # use prepared config by subprocess below
        Popen([python_executable_path, my_app_name, ...).start()

    def _take_tcp_port(self):
        available_found = False
        while not available_found:
            port = random.randint(9000, 9999) # these ints are arbitrary here
            available_found = port not in self._used_tcp_ports
        self._used_tcp_ports.add(port)
        return port

    def stop_my_app(self):
        so_something_that_Im_sure_will_stop_my_app_after_a_few_seconds()
```

Every test case `setUp()` calls `self.start_my_app()`, and every `tearDown()` - `self.stop_my_app()`, and I can rely on stopping my app. I need many instances of my app (and cannot start/stop app in class-wide setup/teardown), because some of my test are checking whether app works well in scenarios starting with empty working directory (I just need "empty" app instance for those tests).

I have a problem with second method, `_take_tcp_port`. Before I introduced it, I often had problems with already taken address (because all tests tried running TCP server on the same port). Now it doesn't happen so often, but still - it happens.

I know that it is system-dependent, and after few seconds port will be available again, but it makes automated testing harder.

**Question:**

How do I check, whether some address (host and port) is available for TCP server? I wanna check it in `_take_tcp_port`, to be sure that test won't fail because app instance has problems with taken port.

**Research I've done:**

I've browsed 1st pages of following google searches:

- check if port is open python
- check if port is available python
- discover available port

and all approaches I've found base on trying to obtain socket. Thing is, if I obtain socket successfully I can be sure that this port WAS open, but because I did it, I cannot be sure that my app will be able to obtain it. I need something without side effects.

**Platform**

This needs to be multiplatform (at least Windows, Linux, MacOS). It must work at least in p3.3+. If "there's a lib for that" that will be enough ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manually scan for an available port--the OS will do it for you.  Just specify port 0 when you call bind() and the OS will choose one.  This is often useful for testing--you can launch one endpoint with port 0, have it ask the system what port it actually got (getsockaddr), then launch the second endpoint with that port number.

Comment: That is useful, but how can I get this port outside of Popened process? Some tests will need to connect to this TCP server, and to be as close to simulating real-life scenarios, I want to run this with Popen, probably with shell=True, to isolate testing process and app processes (instead of calling its main() function in testing process in additional thread, or multiprocessing.Process).

Comment: One option would be to pass a command-line argument to the program via Popen which specifies the name of a file to which the program will write the port number as soon as it knows.  Or even have your launcher listen on any port and have it pass that port number to the child, and the child will use that to send the port number back.  Slightly wacky, that one, but it'd work if you're reluctant to use the filesystem for this IPC.

Comment: This would mean, I need to implement something in app, that has no real usage, but is created just for tests. This I consider bad practice - I'm starting to couple app logic and test logic, and that is not good. Still, probably we're gonna add something that stores used config (copies it) to workspace, so that apps state may be inspected - then, we'll use this approach. Thanks!